# How to remove a line that match a pattern of sepific occurance?

Tags: bash

Here i would like to delete the line that match with
 `<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">` with the fourth occurance

I asked here before but that is a bit different, at that time i only have to match  with `<ul>`

at that time i get the answer:

```
    awk '/<ul>/ {ul++} ul == 6 { getline } 1' file
```

However , that can not be applied to  `<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">`

And in the other post i have got another answer:

```
awk '/<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">/ {a++} a == 4 { getline } 1' file
```

the awk seems have some bug

```
^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I<li><p><a href="anti/recent.html">4 Jul 2011 - Fraudulent email purporting to be related to Standard Chartered Bank (Hong Kong) Limited</a></p></li>$
                                      <!--<li>There is no phishing attack at this  moment.</li>-->$
^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I    </ul>$
```

for example it will delete the `</ul>` as well although that is on the different line?

it somehow works as it delete the fourth item but after that it delete so many line(~40 lines) (and that is totally irrelevant to `<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">`. What are the reasons? Thanks

Comment: i am wondering whether the "a" cause the problem?

Comment: the order of the code has changed as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">/ {a++} a == 4 { getline } 1' file
```

That will delete any line when "a" equals 4, even if they do not match the pattern. You have to combine ("and") the conditions:

```
awk '/<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">/ && ++a == 4 {next} 1' file
```